# Convert object to array with map with typings in TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to convert an object of values coming from Firebase to a typed array of values:

```
const snapshot = await db.teams().once('value');
const teams: Array<ITeam> = Object.entries(snapshot.val()).map(
    ([id, { identifier, name }]): ITeam => {
        return { identifier, name, id };
    }
);
```

Types are modelled like following:

```
export interface ITeam extends ITeamEntry {
    id: string;
}

export interface ITeamEntry {
    identifier: string;
    name: string;
}
```

But I'm getting errors like:

```
Property 'identifier' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
```

I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Shouldn't `ILeague` be a type attribute of `ITeam` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`val` is probably an object with `unknown` properties. To be able to access the properties you will probably need to assert `val` to `Record<string, ITeam>`

```
const teams: Array<ITeam> = Object.entries(snapshot.val() as Record<string, ITeam>).map(
    ([id, { identifier, name }]): ITeam => {
        return { identifier, name, id };
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the `Record` type. I was not aware of it.